# onBlur event in IE

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onblur

I have this HTML:

```
<textarea class="question" onBlur="onBlurFun(event); return true;" 
name="aaa" id="bbb"></textarea>
```

And this function in JavaScript

```
    onBlurFun = function(event) {
 var tgt = $(event.target);
 alert(tgt.attr('id'));
    }
```

In IE, `tgt` is not properly set. What should I do to have access to calling node?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*event.srcElement* is Internet Explorer's equivalent of *event.target*.  jQuery normalizes this for you in event handlers applied using *.bind()*, so you can use *event.target* in Internet Explorer, but event handlers applied through HTML attributes or the DOM properties won't have the property.  In your case, you could change the code to

```
// event.target or event.srcElement
var tgt = $(event.target || event.srcElement);
```

or follow [June R's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422754/problem-with-onblur-event-in-ie/3422777#3422777) and pass in a reference to the element instead.

As a side note, there is no need to `return true;` for most events, but especially for *onblur* and *onfocus* since you can't cancel the default action of them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

To check target do not pass event intead of this pass object it self like

look this code

```
<textarea class="question" onBlur="onBlurFun(this); return true;" 
name="aaa" id="bbb"></textarea>

 function  onBlurFun(obj) 
{
   alert(obj.id); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IE has its own global event object.

This should work

```
onBlurFun = function(event) {

   if (!event)
   {
     event = window.event;
     event.target = event.srcElement;
   }

   var tgt = $(event.target);
   alert(tgt.attr('id'));

}
```